# Who should say the half kaddish after reading the Torah?

Tags: halacha, torah-service, kaddish

Who is supposed to say the chatzi kaddish after the torah reading? Is it the person who read the torah or an ovel who is saying kaddish?

Comment: Why would this be different from any other Kaddish said in the middle of Davening that the Chazan says?

Answer (score 1):

The baal koreh or gabbai says it as it is to separate parts of the davening rather than for a yasom.

[The Kaddish Prayer](http://judaism.about.com/od/prayersworship/a/Forms-of-the-Jewish-Kaddish-Prayer.htm)

> Chatzi Kaddish - the Half Kaddish or Reader's Kaddish
>
> During the morning service (Shacharit) Chatzi Kaddish is recited by
> the prayer leader (usually the rabbi or cantor) after the P'Sukei
> D'Zimra section of the service, after the Amidah prayer, and after the
> Torah service as a means of demarcating different sections of the
> service. During the afternoon and evening services it is recited
> before the Amidah. All versions of the prayer include the Chatzi
> Kaddish.

[What Are the Different Kaddish Prayers?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1835997/jewish/What-Are-the-Different-Kaddish-Prayers.htm)

> The “Half Kaddish,”or chatzi kaddish (Heb. חצי קדיש).
>
> This is composed of several lines beginning with, “May [G‑d’s] great
> name be exalted and holy…” The half kaddish is recited by the one
> leading the prayer, and after each stanza the congregation says,
> “Amen,” which means “correct,” or “it should be that way.” In the
> middle of the prayer, the entire congregation says in unison, “G‑d’s
> great name should be blessed forever and for all eternity.”
>
> The half kaddish is said when the community completes certain sections
> of the prayer service, yet they have not completed the prayer service.
> For example, we say it between the “Verses of Praise” and the
> blessings before the Shema prayer, as well as after reading from the
> Torah Scroll, and so forth.[2]
>
> [2]. See Rabbi Schneur Zalman of Liadi, Code of Jewish Law, Orach Chayim 55:1.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/726345/rabbi-hershel-schachter/lesser-known-laws-of-torah-reading/):

> The Kaddish recited after Keriat Hatarah does not especially "belong"
>   to the Ba'al Keriah. Anyone who is a hiyuv (one who is obligated to
>   say Kaddish that day), may insist on reciting this Kaddish, as well.

In fact, in many shuls that I have attended, a chiyuv - someone who observes yahrtzeit or is in his 1st 11 months of mourning - is the one who says Kaddish after Torah reading and NOT the Torah reader.